# Probability - Am I understanding the problem correctly?

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution

**The problem**

It is given that a certain type of battery has a mean shelf life of 30 months with a standard deviation of 3 months.

For a randomly selected battery let $X$ denote the lifetime of the battery. Assuming a normal distribution:

X ~ Normal($\mu=$ 30, $\sigma=$ 3).

The question asks, for a randomly selected battery, determine the probability that it will break down during the third year.

---

**The solution(?)**

The probability that a randomly selected battery has a lifetime of between 24 and 36 months (i.e. the third year) can be evaluated as:

$p=Pr[24<<36]=Pr[-2<<2]\approx0.955$

where $$ is a standard normal random variable.

Is my understanding correct that *the probability that it will break down during the third year* is $1-p=1-0.955=0.045$?

Comment: No, $1-p$ is the probability that it will break down *outside* of that period.  You just want $p$.

Comment: Was there a particular reason you wanted to do $1-p$? Just $p$ should be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your procedure is correct...thus remove your conclusion but get focus on YOUR CORRECT solution

The probability that the random selected battery will break down between 24° and 36°month is exactly the probability that its life is between that period, thus

$$P(-2<Z<2)\approx0.9545$$